# How do I programmatically fire a command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-commands

I have an `ICommand` that I want to fire (make the execute go) from code; how do I do this?

Comment: If the `Execute()` method isn't doing what you expect, it might help for us to have source code to look at.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try calling the [`Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx) method.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming there is `someCommand` with `commandArgs`:

```
if (someCommand.CanExecute(commandArgs))
{
    someCommand.Execute(commandArgs);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `RoutedUICommand`'s [Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.execute.aspx) and [CanExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.canexecute.aspx), be sure to pass in a valid target so that the correct `CommandBinding` can be found.

Also, if your command's handlers do not modify View objects directly, consider using Kent Boogaart's [DelegateCommand](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html).  Using delegate commands will move the business logic to the ViewModel, which is nice, and they're especially handy if you need execute commands directly from code and you don't have access to the View (or a View object from which you can bubble to your `CommandBindings`).

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you need call another event of internal components, like a click button, see the methods startin with Perform (like PerformClick of a button).

Another answers are okay, use Execute only...